# 403 Forbidden You don't have permission to access / on this server

Tags: .htaccess, wordpress

So I was writing a new post in Wordpress, and suddenly I got this 403 error
    Forbidden

```
You don't have permission to access / on this server.
Apache/2.4.9 (Unix) Server at www.lightwear.co.uk Port 80
```

I searched the web, and tried few fix suggested with renaming the folder plugins to plugins.HOLD

Also checked .htaccess and configured it to:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ – [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Still not having success.
Check the site: http://www.lightwear.co.uk/
Its very frustrating...
Any ideas what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Add this to the top of your .htaccess file and see how it works.

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
```

Otherwise check your permissions on your document root.

Update public_html permission to `755`

Comment: Thanks for the comment
Okay, i did it, still not working...
How do I know what are the correct permissions?

Comment: Are those correct?

    .bash_logout 644
    .bash_profile 644
     .bashrc 644
      ▶
      cgi-bin 711
    .htaccess  644
    logs  777
    php.ini 644
▶
public_html 711

Comment: Okay, so I added this to 

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com$
    RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

still nothing

Comment: So the latest reply i got from my hosting is this:
I've taken a look at the site's access logs, and the following is a list of IPs accessing the site today, with the number on the left corresponding to the number of hits by that IP:
10519 91.140.90.24

Comment: Because of the high number of accesses by specific IPs, it looks like the site has been the victim of a DDoS attack, rather than an increase in traffic since being advertised elsewhere.

What I would recommend in this case, is adding these top IP's to an .htaccess block list in the following format:

Order Allow,Deny
Deny from 91.140.90.24
Deny from etc...

This should prevent issues like this from occurring in future for these specific IPs, and after reviewing the site, we should be able to re-enable this.

Comment: so there was about 20 other IPs in the email I got, but the thing is that this one IP I posted is the IP of my ISP, and now they suggest me to add myself to the blocklist... thats very frustrating, I havent run any DDoS attack on myself, I have just added some of my articles on StumbleUpon, and out of the blue on got over 50k hits in 4 days...